# How to show other model field in my cgridview

Tags: yii-components

I want to show a other model field in my cgrid view , I am using yii model.
My current model is Members and other model is Billing:
My Code:

```
    public function getImportantMembers(){  

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->select ='t.*,b.billing_id,b.amount,b.billing_date,b.member_id,b.billing_status';     
    $criteria->join = 'JOIN billing AS b ON b.member_id = t.id ';

    if(isset($_GET['condition']) AND $_GET['condition'] > 0){
        $condition = $this->getConditionForImportantMembers($_GET['condition']);
        $criteria->addCondition($condition);
    }
    else{    
        $criteria->addCondition("b.billing_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND b.billing_status='c' AND b.amount >= 150 AND t.status='a'");
    }        
    $criteria->group  = 't.id';            

    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'pagination'=>array(
                        'pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
            ),                      
    )); 
}
```

Comment: Show your relation code?

Comment: Thank you I have added you relation code and in view,now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first clear the relation in your member model;

```
'billing'  => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Billing', 'id'),
```

In your view:

```
   $data->billing->amount
```